# Move data from columns B,C,D.. to column A - excel

Tags: excel

Ive got data in columns B1-B20,C1-C20,D1-D20.. Id like to move it to all sit in column A is there an automated way to do this in excel without using VBA ?

Answer (score 1):

Moving it would require a macro

Getting it in A could work with a formula such as the following in A1, then copied down.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROW()-1,20),1+INT((ROW()-1)/20))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way of doing it. It utilized `INDIRECT()`.

```
=IF(ROW()<=20,INDIRECT("B"&ROW()),IF(ROW()<=40,INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-20),INDIRECT("D"&ROW()-40)))
```

Here is an example that does the same thing except I have 3 rows instead of 20.

[image]

Edit: [@nutsch has a more efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790678/2893712)